# Remove gap between images in a flex box

Tags: css, vue.js, duplicates

### [Duplicate]

### answer here [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

I display some images with different sizes along multiple rows.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHelq.png)

But there are gaps between the rows. I've tried a lot, but couldn't find why.

```
<div class="muralBox">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div v-for="(topAlbum, i) in topAlbumInfo.value" :key="topAlbum.name" class="albums"> 
      <Album :info="topAlbum" :width="layoutConfig[i].width"/>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in Album.vue

```
 <img :src="img" :width="width" :height="width" alt=""/>
```

And css:

```
.muralBox {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #1f1c2c;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: What styles do you have for `div.albums`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you wanted since I can't see how you styled them, but I just gave images 100% height and width and that basically did it in a codepen.

[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/shammlo/pen/NWaGzdG?editors=1100)

```
    .albums img{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
     }
```